# How to get width and height PDF page by Imagick?

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, imagick

I use package [pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) for Yii2 based on Imagick library to convert each page of PDF to image. Also I need to get width and height or format of particular PDF page. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @RaymondNijland width and height from the PDF page

Comment: library (Imagick if you mean that) does not have any tools for getting pdf size. And it does not generate PDF it generates images from PDF file.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getnumberimages.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageindex.php   https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimage.php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagewidth.php

You might be able to do this with pingImage, rather than loading the image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach? 
By Imagick I can easily get image from pdf file
    
    `$RESOLUTION = 300;
    $myurl = 'filename.pdf['.$pagenumber.'];'
    $image = new Imagick($myurl);
    $image->setResolution( $RESOLUTION , $RESOLUTION );
    $image->setImageFormat( "png" );
    $image->writeImage('newfilename.png');`

Now I have image from page of PDF file. I know resolution (number pixels per inch) and I can get width and height of image in pixels. So don't need to have deep knowledge in math to calculate width and height of page of PDF in inch:
    
    `$pdfPageWidth = $imageWidth / $RESOLUTION;
    $pdfPageHeight = $imageHeght/ $RESOLUTION;`

Answer (score 1):

Imagick is a native php extension to create and modify images using the ImageMagick API. So doesn't retry any PDF's info but image's info:

> Imagick::getNumberImages — Returns the number of **images** in the
>   object.
>
> $pdf->getNumberOfPages(); //returns number of images that are equal to number of PDF's pages. This is a method from pdf-to-image package.

A PDF describes the content and appearance of one or more pages. It also contains a definition of the physical size of those pages. That page size definition is not as straightforward as you might think. There can in fact be up to **5** different definitions in a PDF that relate to the size of its pages. These are called the boundary boxes or page boxes.

The MediaBox is used to specify the width and height of the page. For the average user, this probably equals the actual page size.

Each page in a PDF can have different sizes for the various page boxes.

A PDF always has a MediaBox definition. All the other page boxes do not necessarily have to be present in regular PDF files.

The MediaBox is the largest page box in a PDF. The other page boxes can equal the size of the MediaBox but they are not expected to be larger (The latter is explicitly required in the PDF/X-4 requirements). If they are larger, the PDF viewer will use the values of the MediaBox.

You should be able to retrieve the exact "HiResBoundingBox" value (which is the MediaBox value in PDF).

A test document is A4 (210mm x 297mm) which is **595.28**pt x **841.89**pt and has four(4) pages.

The unit of these values is PostScript points (where 72 pt == 1 inch).

```
$pdf = "1.pdf";
$output = shell_exec("identify -format \"%[pdf:HiResBoundingBox]\" $pdf");
echo $output;
```

prints this String:

**595.28**x**841.89**+0+0**595.28**x**841.89**+0+0**595.28**x**841.89**+0+0**595.28**x**841.89**+0+0

with some **REGEX** you could get width:**595.28pt** and height:**841.89pt** for each page and convert them to millimeters.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this command "identify -format \"%[pdf:HiResBoundingBox]\" $pdf" should work in terminal ubuntu, right (where $pdf is path to pdf file)? Why I get ''identify: command not found"?

Comment: That's because you don't have Imagick library installed on your SERVER

From a terminal, run the following command:
`sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

For Mac users, just run the command:
`brew install imagemagick`

Comment: what do you think about my solution? please look at my answer

Comment: by my solution I get the same value and it works slightly faster than by command "identify"

Comment: Yes I like your solution, but it has a different approach. In my solution i get ALL the sizes from a PDF document(remember a PDF doc could have different size pages on it) in your solution you invest time and effort in 1) pass the specific $pagenumber and 2) you are generating a newfile.png As I can see in your question you ask for **a way** to get width and height or format of particular PDF page. Remember with your solution, you're working with **images already generated** from the library, if you are not generate them, then you can not access to those values but YES your solution will work

Comment: @RomanYakoviv I used code similar to yours, only extra thing was i deleted each file with "unlink"  after reading it. It takes a huge time to execute in case of pdfs with large number of pages..

Comment: If contributors are still here, I found the solution provided by @CarlosManzo satisfying, as it takes slightly lesser time to execute.. However problem is, it does not return any result in some pdf files.. It maybe that the pdf itself is malformed somehow.. I am running this size check along with few other checks on a file that user uploads.. It is performed over ajax and so, I need the fastest way to get the page dimensions of each page on the pdf uploaded..